# how to import scrapy spider to another code

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a simple scrapy spider and then used [Run Scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) , to convert to a python script which I can run as a standalone script.

How can I integrate into an another code

my_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

another_code.py

```
#certain operations
list_of_urls = [...]
#run the spider on this list
```

a list of urls which I want to pass to the spider, I am looking for a solution that doesn't invovle `os` i.e `os.system('python myspider.py -a my_list')`, is there a way of importing the spider and running it from code?

Comment: What part don’t you know how to handle? Passing `list_of_urls` as a spider parameter when using `CrawlerProcess`?

Comment: @Gallaecio yes, I tried importing directly `from my_spider import MySpider` then ran then made `process` but it just gave me twisted error

Comment: You can pass spider parameters to [`crawl()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.crawl)

Comment: how will this effect the twisted error?

Comment: That depends on the Twisted error. If you are getting the ReactorNotRestartable error, and you cannot refactor your code not to call process.start() more than once, then `os.system` or a `POpen` equivalent would be the best option, I think.